# C changing size of the array inside struct

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1

struct Cases
    {
        char name[3];
        int cases;
    };



int main()
{
    int n=5;
    struct Cases Real;
    Real.name[0] = 'a';
    Real.name[1] = 'b';
    Real.name[2] = 'c';
    printf("Size before: %d \n", sizeof Real.name);
    Real.name = (char *)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Size after: %d \n", sizeof Real.name);


    return 0;
}
```

Hi, i am trying to change the size of the array inside structure, but it gives error. I tried to do it first empty array but that didn't work out aswell. Any help ?

Comment: `Real.name = (char *)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));` `name` is not a pointer thus you cannot change its size on the go.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, pointers are not arrays. I suggest you read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c. faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: You might be able to use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

Answer (score 2):

> *Hi, i am trying to change the size of the array inside structure*

You cannot change the size of an array, it's a constant. If you try to assign to a variable of any array type, you'll see error, as an array is not a modifiable lvalue.

As an alternative: You can define a pointer, and allocate memory dynamically using the allocator functions (as you tried).

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible without the use of `pointers`, an example for you to be able to do this with `pointers`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
     char **real = malloc (3 * sizeof (* array));
     real[0] = "a";
     real[1] = "b";
     real[2] = "c";

     printf ("% My array in position 0 n", real[0]);

     char ** tmp = realloc (real, 5 * sizeof (* array));
     real = tmp;
     real[1] = "G";

     printf ("% s \ n", real [0]);
     printf ("% s \ n", real [1]);
         

     free (array);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something close to that with a flexible array :

```
struct Cases
{
        int cases;
        char name[]; //Must be the last element in the struct   
};

int main()
{
    struct Cases * real = (struct Cases *)malloc(sizeof(struct Cases) + 3 * sizeof(char));
    real->length  = 3;
    real->name[0] = 'a';
    real->name[1] = 'b';
    real->name[2] = 'c';
    printf("%d\n", real->length);           //=> 3
    
    real = (struct Cases *)realloc(real, sizeof(struct Cases) + 5 * sizeof(char));
    real->length  = 5;
    real->name[3] = 'd';
    real->name[4] = 'e';
    printf("%d\n", real->length);           //=> 5

    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(real));          //=> 8 (the size of the pointer)
    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(struct Cases));  //=> 8 (the size of the structure without the array)
    
    free(real);
    return 0;
}
```

However you must memorize the size by yourself (I added a field to the structure for that purpose).

Answer (score 0):

As you've defined it, `name` is an array of three elements, inside a `struct`. As such, its size cannot be changed. If you want to be able to change the size dynamically, you can declare it as a `char` pointer, then allocate the storage dynamically (and free it when done).

Here's an example of what this might look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Cases
{
    char *name;
    int cases;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Cases Real;

    Real.name = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    if (Real.name == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Real.name[0] = 'a';
    Real.name[1] = 'b';
    Real.name[2] = 'c';

    Real.name = realloc(Real.name, 5 * sizeof(char));
    if (Real.name == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Realloc failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Real.name[3] = 'd';
    Real.name[4] = 'e';

    free(Real.name);

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, `name` is now a `char` pointer, which is first set with `malloc` to be able to hold 3 elements.  It is later grown with `realloc` to be able to hold 5 elements.  Finally, it is freed by calling `free`.

Under normal circumstances, this example doesn't print anything out.  It will print an error message if either `malloc` or `realloc` fails.  You should always check the result of `malloc` or `realloc` to see if it's `NULL` before attempting to use it.

Note that these arrays do not have a terminating null character in the example (although you could certainly add one if desired, provided you've allocated space for it).  Also note that `sizeof` is no longer useful when used on `name`, since `name` is now a pointer.  You need to keep track of the size yourself.  If needed, you could add a `size` field to `Cases`, setting it to the current size.